# Adding custom header to WebView by adding headers to WebResourceRequest's headers in shouldInterceptRequest doesn't work

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to add a custom header to a page loading in WebView, but it doesn't work, header is not set:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view,  WebResourceRequest request)
{
    request.getRequestHeaders().add("MyHeader","MyValue"); 
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? I'm running on Android 5.

I've seen many answers on SO saying that you have to do the HTTP request and return `WebResourceResponse` yourself. Is this because even if you modify headers like I do, they are ignored?

I also trying to find the location in the Android source code of the call to 
Where is the location of the call to the shouldInterceptRequest so I can see how it works myself, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Is your minSdkVersion is set to 21, since `shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view,  WebResourceRequest request)` is supported from version 21 only

Comment: yes. it should work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer myself, it's right there in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)):

> If the return value is null, the WebView will continue to load the
>   resource as usual. Otherwise, the return response and data will be
>   used.

Moreover, a simple test shows the base implementation of `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest` returns `null`. So the WebView basically continues to load resource as usual.

In other words, I cannot just add a value to header and expect it to be used. 
I actually need to do the request myself and return the response.

Too bad there is no way to just modify header and have the default implementation use it.

I know I can set in headers by calling `loadUrl` method with headers, but the headers won't be used if I'm first loading a local page and then load online pages.

Comment: I wouldn't expect your first approach to work because you are just retrieving a set of headers, and adding another item to the set. You aren't actually assigning the new set to the request. The tricky part is assigning the new set of headers because there is no setHeaders method in WebResourceRequest

Comment: @Chicowitz getRequestHeaders() returns a HashMap instance, which is the same instance inside the request, not a copy. The request references the same instance. Meaning if you add values to it, the additional values are already in the request. You don't need assign the "new set", there is no new set, it's the same set. So that's not why it doesn't work. You're just confusing matters. Don Box already stated exactly why it doesn't work in this answer.

Comment: @Don Box Did you find any other workaround for the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Default method implementation of `shouldInterceptRequest` provided in the WebViewClient is returning null, hence if we need additional headers to be set then we have to create WebResourceResponse and return it.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewClient.java

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a custom header to the *response* using this code in one of my shouldInterceptRequest  handlers:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes());
WebResourceResponse resp = new WebResourceResponse("text/html", null, is);
Map<String, String> hdrs = resp.getResponseHeaders();
Map<String, String> newHdrs = new HashMap<>();
if(hdrs != null) newHdrs.putAll(hdrs);
newHdrs.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
resp.setResponseHeaders(newHdrs);
return resp;
```

Note that this is 5 years after the original post and I'm coding to API 30

Comment: what is the result here? Is it the httpresult?